# How is the correct way to add specific information for Resource Server inside OAuth2 access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have a scenario where my Resource Server (RS) can connect to multiple databases and it can be multi-tenant. It has an environment configuration where I can say: Env A points to database A and belongs to tenant A; Env B points to database B and belongs to tenant B;

Our desktop apps store that information in a data structure that is sent to RS on every call and our web apps store it inside ASP.NET Session. The user select the environment at login.

Now we are moving our APIs completely to REST services and protecting them with oAuth2 using IdentityServer4.

I need to send that environment value to the APIs and I think that should be part of the access token.

The first question is: Is that correct? Can a access token have that kind of information?

The second is: Which is the best IdentityServer4 service that I should extend to inject that value as a claim inside access token and consequently inside ClaimsPrincipal.

The third is: Sometimes I don't have a user to select the environment at login (client credentials grant, for example). In this case, is the correct treat environment as a client claim? There is a way to have dynamic client claims?

Sorry about the long question!

Regards,
Diogo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that claim is about the users (or clients) identity - yes - it is a candidate for the token.

Add the claim to the resource scopes that represent your API - this way the claim type will be requested in the profile service and you can add it to the token.

Client claims are not dynamic though.

Comment: Well, that claim is a user choice at login. So, inside my profile service I can get that claim value from the session, for example, and add it to the token.

For Client credentials, maybe the only way would be create several clients, each one with a specific claim for environment. This way, the DefaultClaimsService will already add it to the token.

What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Sounds OK to me